# Syntax error in a partial with no Rails code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, erb

I feel like I'm going crazy, but I had a partial that was working fine, then all the sudden I started getting the following error when I refreshed the view:

`syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting keyword_end`

I narrowed it down to a single snippet of HTML code. I get the error when I reduce my partial down to just this single line of code, with no ERB expressions or anything else in the file:

`<div id="product-variants"/>`

But, if I change my partial to contain something similar, like any of these, I don't get the syntax error and it goes on to render my view:

`<div id="aproduct-variants"/>`

`product-variants`

`<div id="product-variant"/>`

I've tried restarting my server, but I still see the same behavior. I checked for weird special characters, but I don't have any. And my filename seems to be OK: `_cart_form.html.erb`

Why in the world would the parser get confused by the value of an HTML attribute? Is this some sort of weird caching issue in my development environment? Do I need to clean something up on my filesystem?

Comment: What's the / for at the end of your div?  normal div syntax would be <div id="product-variant"></div>, perhaps that's confusing the erb parser?

Comment: That's the standard way to define any HTML element that doesn't have any content. Regardless, that's not the problem, I boiled it down to the </div> version first, then reduced it even further to get what I have in the question.

Comment: I find the better_errors gem very useful when trying to isolate weird bugs https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors     
http://railscasts.com/episodes/402-better-errors-railspanel

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I use better_errors all the time. But, this isn't a runtime error, it is a parsing error. I don't even have a chance to get to a better_errors screen before the problem occurs.

Comment: Do you think it's something trying to modify your HTML before/after that HTML id? Deface maybe?

Comment: @JesseWolgamott - Haha, I just posted my answer and then saw your comment. Spot on!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just figured it out. We're using Deface (https://github.com/spree/deface) to override some views and "product-variants" happened to be the name of the matching element that we're using to insert some view code. The deface override had a syntax error, but unfortunately, the stack didn't show that to me.